# 301 redirect to different page on different domain?

Tags: redirects, search-engine-indexing, 301-redirect

I want to make a 301 redirect to a different page on a different domain.  The page is on the same topic, but is different content.

Also, the traffic to the original page comes from the alt text on an image.  I'm sure that the alt text is different on the same image from the other page.

Is this wise to do and will it last?  Or, should 301 redirects only be done when it's the exact same content?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand your second sentence.
It's perfectly fine to use 301 redirect even if the content of the page is different, redirecting to another domain is called "domain redirection" or "domain forwarding".

What you want to avoid is using "302 redirect" which means "moved temporarily".

You might be interested in reading more about 301 redirect, I recommend going over [this](http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/redirection) and [this](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633).

Comment: Thanks!  Here's what I meant...  The page I'm going to redirect to is different than the original page; similar, but different content.  Will this be sustainable?  Or does the content have to be identical for a 301 redirect?

Comment: I understood: "It's perfectly fine to use 301 redirect even if the content of the page is different" :)